# How to apply different jsonview on each element of arraylist java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to get a list of object in response using rest-controller. But I want to apply different-different json view on each element of response list based on some condition in my java code.

For example:

```
class Emp{
   int id;
   String name;
   int age;
}
```

Required response

```
[{
  1, "KK",23
},
{2,"PK"
},
{ 3, "CK"
},]
```

You can see above that, in second and third object, there is not age, but in first, we have. I need response as above.

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: What is the condition to have a different view? The position in the array?

Comment: here, we can say, for example. age is lesser than 23. we don't want to include them in our response.